# LINQ To XML Getting a value without the nodes inside

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have this XML:

```
<chunk type="manufacturer_info" id="" note="">test: <chunk type="style" style="link">${manufacturer_website}</chunk></chunk>
```

I need to get "test: " separately from the inner  element.

EDIT:
This is coming into a function as an XElement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <chunk> element has two child nodes: a text node and a <chunk> element.

You can get the value of the text node as follows:

```
var element = XElement.Parse(@"<chunk type=""manufacturer_info"" ...");

var result = string.Concat(element.Nodes().OfType<XText>());
// result == "test: "
```

Comment: That returns "${manufacturer_name}" how would I just get "test: "?

Comment: @Ryan: It returns "test:" on the XML you posted, so this answer is correct.

Comment: It may be because I have it coming in as an XElement into a function. Would I still need to create the XDocument?

Comment: @Ryan: Replace `doc.Root` with the `XElement` representing the outer `<chunk>` element.

Comment: in this case there is no outer <chunk> element just what I have shown.. Sorry does that make sense?

Comment: @Ryan: your example clearly contains two <chunk> element: one is the child element of the other one. So there is an "inner" and an "outer" <chunk> element. My code returns `"test: "` for the outer <chunk> element. It compiles and runs on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
          string xml =  @"<Chunks><chunk type='manufacturer_info' id='' note=''>test:                <chunk type='style' style='link'>${manufacturer_website}</chunk></chunk></Chunks>";

          var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
          var res = xDoc.DescendantNodes().OfType<XText>().First().Value;
```